# How to stop the number from rounding up when using setprecision?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

```
const double MIN_STD_POWER = 90.111;
const double MAX_STD_POWER = 99.999;
double m_size = 2;

void display() const
{
    if (m_size == MAX_STD_POWER || m_size == MIN_STD_POWER)
    {
        cout << m_size << " liters - " << m_type << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << m_size << " liters - " << m_type << endl;
    }
}
```

So basically, I'm trying to print `m_size` to two significant digits, but not the `MAX_STD_POWER` because it keeps rounding off to `100.00` instead of `99.999`. **Why doesn't the above work?**

Example of the output I want:

```
4.10 - liters 
2.10 - liters 
2.10 - liters 
2.10 - liters 
Ship doesn't exceed power regulation of: 99.999
```

Example of the output I get:

```
4.10 - liters 
2.10 - liters 
2.10 - liters 
2.10 - liters 
Ship doesn't exceed power regulation of: 100.00
```

Comment: The sample output doesn't match the code, in the code there is always a hyphen after the `liters`. Also you say that it is printing 100.00 instead of 99.999, but then in the sample output it shows 99.999.  It would improve the question to post the exact output you are getting and explain how it is not expected

Comment: Please make the example that can be literally copied and compiled locally. The current one doesn't produce the showed output.

Comment: Are you aware of the risks of comparing equal two floating point numbers? https://wandbox.org/permlink/Eg2LcS8EkUEnv7bG

Answer (score 1):

Round it to three decimals, when you need three, and round it to two, when you need two ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/gxrY7Y)).

```
void display() const
{
    const int precision = (m_size == MAX_STD_POWER || m_size == MIN_STD_POWER) ? 3 : 2;
    cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << m_size << " liters - " << m_type << endl;
}
```

Comment: i tried that but it always prints out the right side

Comment: I have added a link to a live demo. Try it. It should show you, that it works. If you still have a question, then ask. I don't know, what you mean by "the right side" by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are going to round (to the nearest) when printed.

Part of the problem is that these numbers:

```
90.111
99.999
```

May not be represented exactly in a floating point number. Its probably very close but not exact. When I print these out with lots of precision I get:

```
99.998999999999995
90.111000000000004

2 significant digits:
1e+02
 90

3 significant digits:
100
 90.1

5 significant digits:
 99.999
 90.111
```

Simplest way to "round down is truncating to an integer.

```
int printable = m_size * 100; // 100 2 significant digits.
std::cout << (printable / 100) << "." << (printable % 100) << "\n"
```

But you can use doubles with in this situation.

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << m_size << "\n";
```

Simple rule of thumb: Only use floating point were you really need it (the range of value is continuous not discrete). If you are storing something with some level of precession (ie to the nearest thousandth) store in an integer but multiply by 1000 so you store the value exactly. You only need to convert when printing and then simply use divide to get the integer part and mod to get the fraction part.

Comment: I dont quite understand this , if i truncate m_size everything will be affected .